# incorrect ranking power bi-dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, ranking, rank

I HAVE AN ARRAY WITH THE FOLLOWING DATA

```
group    mat    value
 1       a1      10
         a2      23
         a3       1
         ..
         an      32

2        b1      10
         b2       2
         b3      23
         ..
         bn       1
```

i want to get a rank but instead of giving me values like
1
2
3
..
10

i get the following

```
group    mat    value   rank
 1       a1      10     12
         a2      23     23
         a3       1     40
         ..
         an      32     3

2        b1      10     11
         b2       2     39
         b3      23     24
         ..
         bn       1     42
```

this is my formula:

```
RANKX( FILTER( 'table','table'[group]  = EARLIER('tabla'[group])),'tabla'[value], , DESC)
```

and I have other fields to filter such as center and date but they are not in the matrix display
any idea how to change my ranking? Tanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First using Transform Data, Fill down values for Group column

[image]

Then write a measure

```
Measure = SUM(Data[value])
```

Then write a Rank measure

```
Rank = RANKX(ALLEXCEPT(Data, Data[group]), [Measure])
```

If you want filter on center and date then give those columns in ALLEXCEPT filter

```
Rank = RANKX(ALLEXCEPT(Data, Data[group], Data[center], Data[Date]), [Measure])
```

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly for me if I use a table as a visualization, but when using matrix it gives me an error.
Error Message:
 The operation was canceled because of locking conflicts.

Comment: https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/The-operation-was-cancelled-because-of-locking-conflicts/td-p/1230534